# Using React Hooks only; incre and decre the count asynch after 1 second you click the button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

--2 **buttons for incrementing and decrementing the count asynchronously(for ex: 1s after the click, then increment the count)--**
I tried but couldn't do it so anyone could you please help me. how to generate this asynchronous count randomly and implement this button after 1sec of click every time while increment and decrement both.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Counter = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  /*const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);
  
  ////// to Set timeout//////
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setSeconds((seconds) => seconds + 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => interval;
  }, []);
  */

  const synincrement = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  };

  const syndecrement = () => {
    setCount(count - 1);
  };
  const incrementAsync = () => {
    /*setInterval(() => {
      setSeconds((seconds) => seconds + 1);
    });
    //////// tried to implement 1sec after the click, then increment the count but need a teacher assistant for asynchronous/////////
    */
    setCount(count + 5);
  };
  

  const decrementAsync = () => {
    setCount(count -8);
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}>
      <div>
        <h2>This is Counter App</h2>
        <p style={{ fontSize: 50 }}>{count}</p>
        <button
          onClick={synincrement}
          style={{ fontsize: 30, marginRight: 10, padding: 10 >SynIncrement</button>
        <button
          onClick={syndecrement}
          style={{ fontsize: 30, marginRight: 10, padding: 10 }}>SynDecreme</button>
        <div>

            <button
              onClick={incrementAsync}
              style={{
                fontsize: 30,
                marginRight: 10,
                padding: 10,
                marginTop: 10,
              }}>AsynIncremen</button>
    <button onClick={decrementAsync}
              style={{
                fontsize: 30,
                marginRight: 10,
                padding: 10,
                marginTop: 10,
              }}
            >
              AsynDecrement
            </button>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Counter;
```

Answer (score 0):

Good username by the way @HelloWorld.
I have answered your question. There are 3 things.

1. I prettier'ed your code for understanding.
2. Removed unwanted comments
3. You dont need `useEffect` for this implementation
4. You need to use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`
5. `setCounter` takes function instead of the state as its argument, because it needs to have the latest counter value after 1 second. Otherwise, it will contain the counter state value at the time of setTimeout call.

Here is the code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const incrementPeriod = 1000 // in millisecond
const decrementPeriod = 1000 // in millisecond

const Counter = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const synincrement = () => {
    setCount(count => count + 1);
  };

  const syndecrement = () => {
    setCount(count => count - 1);
  };
  const incrementAsync = () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setCount(count => count + 1);
        }, incrementPeriod)
  };

  const decrementAsync = () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setCount(count => count - 1);
        }, decrementPeriod)
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}>
      <div>
        <h2>This is Counter App</h2>
        <p style={{ fontSize: 50 }}>{count}</p>
        <button
          onClick={synincrement}
          style={{ fontsize: 30, marginRight: 10, padding: 10 }}
        >
          SynIncrement
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={syndecrement}
          style={{ fontsize: 30, marginRight: 10, padding: 10 }}
        >
          SynDecreme
        </button>
        <div>
          <button
            onClick={incrementAsync}
            style={{
              fontsize: 30,
              marginRight: 10,
              padding: 10,
              marginTop: 10,
            }}
          >
            Async Increment
          </button>
          <button
            onClick={decrementAsync}
            style={{
              fontsize: 30,
              marginRight: 10,
              padding: 10,
              marginTop: 10,
            }}
          >
            Async Decrement
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Counter;
```